# Getting error on TryUpdateModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm getting error while using `TryUpdateModel` for updating the model with the posted value.
Error is:

> The property 'ID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

I have set ID as primary key in the database table. Any help would be appreciated.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Edit hotel for the event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">Eventinstance ID</param>
    /// <param name="form">Form parameters</param>
    /// <returns>return the new added hotel model to view</returns>
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditHotelForEvent(int id, FormCollection form)
    {

        EventHotelDetail hoteldetails = eventRepo.getHotelbyID(id);
        if (ModelState.IsValid && TryUpdateModel(hoteldetails)) // update the model with the form values
        {
            hoteldetails.isDefault = true;
            EventRepository.ApplyModifiedProperties(hoteldetails);
            ViewData["success"] = "Hotel added successfully";
            eventRepo.Save();
        }
        return View("AddHotelForEvent", hoteldetails);
    }
```

Comment: debug and get the values within `form` and `hoteldetails` please. there might be an unwanted ID within your FormCollection. can you paste the Form in your view, too?

Comment: `TryUpdateModel` should not throw an error. Which line is throwing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify the primary key (ID in your case).

Why would you like to change the id? id is a unique number that should have no meaning but being unique to a specific object, and therefore should not be modified. if you want another object create another one, but don't trying modifying the id.

**Edit:**

Check these instructions, primary key might be missing from your database:

Step 1: Check whether your table is having primary key column in database or not. If it does not have any primary key than add a primary key. Because if we don't add a primary key to table than entity framework creates its own key collection and add all columns in it.

Step 2: Open your .edmx file to see table object mapping. You will be able to see each column of table is having icon like primary key. So Write click on your page and update .edmx from database.

Step 3: If you still see same primary key icons on all columns than click on column name you want to update one by one and go to property window and Set Entity Key property to false.

Taken from [here](http://blogershub.com/Archive/2013/10/The-property-is-part-of-the-object-key-information-and-cannot-be-modified#.VFzH4vmUffQ).

Answer (score 1):

The error message clearly states the problem. You're trying to modify the primary key of the entity and it's not allowed.

Comment: I m not using the ID value anywhere in my code. Its just for fetching the old data which is to be updated by posted model.

Comment: please provide the code part where you get the error.

Comment: EventHotelDetail hoteldetails = eventRepo.getHotelbyID(id);
 if (ModelState.IsValid && TryUpdateModel(hoteldetails))

Comment: paste the full function to your question please.